# Parsing of ISO 8601 time intervals in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am building a front end component to allow users to choose a date\time range and optionally use time periods as per the ISO 8601 specification.

The component will need to bind to any existing values already set by the user, and so I am looking at how to parse out the time interval period piece for a string such as:

"2007-03-01T13:00Z/P1Y2M10DT2H30M"

I am unsure how to extract the numerical parts of the time interval piece so I can get some sort of object\array, keyed by the letters perhaps so I can easily determine number of years (Y), months (M), etc.

I could have a go at my own regex, but I suspect someone out there has already done this.

I'm wanting to give users a series of number inputs and just set these for any existing period values the user has set previously.

Can anyone suggest any approaches here?

I hope this makes sense!

Thanks

Comment: As always, moment js

Comment: Now now guys!! Thanks for the replies, I did look at moment but was unsure if it supported time periods

Comment: Ooh I like the look of that approach, will give that a go!

Comment: oops, strike my prev comment and use this: `"2007-03-01T13:00Z/P1Y2M10DT2H30M".split("/").pop().split(/\D+/).map(Number).slice(1,-1)` gives you a numerical [Y,M,D,H,M] array. (i took out the filter(), which would shift the array if something were zero)

Comment: dandavis -Thanks for this suggestion, this indeed gives me back an array, but I have no way of knowing which value represents which time piece. Is there a way to get a keyed object e.g. {P:1, Y:2,..}?

Comment: moment.js is actually just what I needed after all - http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var dateStr = '2007-03-01T13:00Z/P1Y2M10DT2H30M';
var date = new Date(Date.parse(dateStr.split('/')[0]));
```

Comment: `=new Date(dateStr.split('/')[0]);` is plenty, but read the question more closely...